# ASPNET5 .Net Core support for MySql EntityFramework

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, clr, coreclr

I am trying to start a new ASP.NET 5 c# project in vs2015 which will include:

- website (new)
- WebAPI (new)
- MySQL db (existing)

... and I need to use entity framework for DB, preferably EF7.

Initially, I selected coreclr runtime, as I need it to be platform independent.

But after a couple of days of research, it came down to clr and mysql EF6.
Now I have a working prototype with these parameters, but I guess I will not have the ability to deploy it on a Linux finally...

As I see it, the problem is:
On the one hand, there is no support from EF7 and mysql.
And on the other, I cannot have mysql EF6 and coreclr runtime.

Is this correct?
Is there anything I am missing, any suggestion?

Comment: If I add DNXCore 5.0 in project.json I get a bunch of errors... one of them is "The dependency EntityFramework 6.1.3 in project WebAPI does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0"

Comment: The new framework won't be ready until RTM and third party bits might take longer to adapt to it.

Comment: Thank you LexLi..! yet, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: wait, or do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year after, this question seems a bit outdated... but let me answer it, so it doesn't stay unanswered...

With **ef core** there is now official support for MySql as well as 2 more providers (Pomelo and Sapient Guardian):

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/)